# Disprove the statement by giving a counterexample.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, examples-counterexamples

I am confused about this question. It says

> Disprove the statement by giving a counterexample.
>
> For all positive integers $n$, $n^2- 2n$ is positive.

Then it gives me these choices:

4

1

0

1/2

2

So I did my math and pugged in the first one (4)

And got $4^2 - 2(4) = 16 - 8 = 8$

So would I check mark $4$ as a answer, or do I need a answer where the final result is NOT positive, like plugging in $1$, which will give me a answer of $-1$ ?

Comment: By n(2)-2(n), do you mean $n^2-2n$ or $n^2-2^n$? NOTE: Michael Hardy just edited your answer, so it looks like you said $2^4=8$, which is not true.

Comment: The first one you wrote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A counterexample means an example where the condition is true, but the conclusion is false.

- The condition is usually the part of the statement that comes after "if..." or "for all..." Here, the condition is "$n$ is a positive integer" because the statement says "for all positive integers $n$, ...".
- The conclusion is the other part of the statement. Here, the conclusion would be "$n^2-2n$ is a positive integer."

Therefore, $n=1$ or $n=2$ would be valid counterexamples because they are positive integers AND $n^2-2n$ is not positive. Both the condition is true and the conclusion is false.

However, $n=0$ and $n=1/2$ would not be valid counterexamples because the condition is not true: They are not positive integers.

Answer (score 0):

You want to *disprove* the statement, so you want to produce an answer that makes the statement "$n^2 -2n$ is positive" incorrect. A counterexample would be an *integer* value of $n$ which shows this to be false; choose $n = 1$.

Comment: Yes, and wouldn't 1/2 also come out to be a negative number? So that too right?

Comment: @JDog No, $0$ and $1/2$ are not good counterexamples because they are not positive integers. Please read my answer to understand this more.

Comment: Ok thanks Ill mark it as right after 5 min